# How do I get elapsed time in the rest interface with ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

How do I get elapsed query time in the REST interface with ArangoDB? (an additional json field with the elapsed time)

Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate this please? Which rest calls? FOXX services? Parts of FOXX services? AQL queries?

Comment: AQL queries with REST interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to get profile information for the different execution phases of AQL queries via [setting the `profile` option to true](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/how-to-invoke-aql/with-arangosh/#profile).

It can be done in arangosh like this:

```
q = "FOR doc IN _users RETURN doc";
s = db._createStatement({ query: q, options: { profile: true } });
res = s.execute().getExtra();
```

The resulting json of the `getExtra()` will look like that:

```
{
  "stats" : { 
    "writesExecuted" : 0, 
    "writesIgnored" : 0, 
    "scannedFull" : 1, 
    "scannedIndex" : 0, 
    "filtered" : 0 
  }, 
  "profile" : { 
    "initializing" : 0.0000040531158447265625, 
    "parsing" : 0.00003600120544433594, 
    "optimizing ast" : 0.0000040531158447265625, 
    "instantiating plan" : 0.000010967254638671875, 
    "optimizing plan" : 0.000023126602172851562, 
    "executing" : 0.00004601478576660156 
  }, 
  "warnings" : [ ] 
}
```

Comment: Could you inform me please an example with curl?

Comment: Sniffing arangosh: `ngrep -Wbyline port  8529 -d lo`  gives this: `POST /_db/_system/_api/cursor HTTP/1.0\n\n   
{"query":"FOR doc IN _users RETURN doc","count":false,"bindVars":{},"options":{"profile":true}}
`